# Formatting Javascript ouput

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code inside a bootstrap modal - the data is being pulled from a button (that triggers the modal)

```
<script> 
  $('#myFavorites').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { 
    // Heart Icon triggers 
    var heart = $(event.relatedTarget) 
    // Button that triggered the modal 
    // List of variables 
    var user = heart.data('user') 
    var title = heart.data('track') 
    var artist = heart.data('artist') 

    // Print to screen 
    var modal = $(this) modal.find('.modal-title').html('User: ' + user + '<p>Song: ' + title + '</p><p>Artist: ' + artist) 
    // modal.find('.modal-body input').val(title) 
  }) 
</script>
```

This all prints out on one line. How can I format it like so (with simple breaks to a new line):

User: 01
Song: Title Here
Artist: Artist Name Here
Source: URL Here
Poster: Poster Here

I injected the \n in several places but it broke the code?

Comment: `<br>`?  `<pre>`?

Comment: Use Bootstrap's output formatting classes like `col-md3`, or create an HTML table.

Comment: As stated below - the HTML is not being recognized or a simple BR would work, as others have suggested. So even though this is a great suggestion, if a BR doesn't work, then table tags wont... hmmm

Answer (score 2):

Use `<br/>` for new line break and use `html` function instead of `text` function:

```
modal.find('.modal-title').html('User: ' + user + '<br/>Song: ' + title + '<br/>Artist: ' + artist + '<br/>Source: ' + source + '<br/>Poster: ' + poster)
```

Comment: I tried that but the output is: User: 2<br/>Song: After Midnight<br/>Artist: Blink 182<br/>Source: https://youtu.be/H86730HjLVA<br/> --- the breaks are not recognized...?

Comment: While XHTML syntax (`<br />`) is legal, there really is no good reason to use it unless you will need to treat your HTML as XML (which these days would be very rare). If anything, it causes confusion and results in users using that self-terminating syntax in places where they shouldn't (i.e. `<script src="..." />`).

Comment: Are you using `html` function instead of `text`? @Davo

Comment: Here is the complete script:

Comment: <script>
   $('#myFavorites').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    
    // Heart Icon triggers
    var heart = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    
    // List of variables
    var user = heart.data('user')
    var title = heart.data('track')
    var artist = heart.data('artist')
    
    // Print to screen
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('User: ' + user + '<p>Song: ' + title + '</p><p>Artist: ' + artist)
    
    // modal.find('.modal-body input').val(title)
   })
  </script>

Comment: Try this:
`<script> $('#myFavorites').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { // Heart Icon triggers var heart = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal // List of variables var user = heart.data('user') var title = heart.data('track') var artist = heart.data('artist') // Print to screen var modal = $(this) modal.find('.modal-title').html('User: ' + user + '<p>Song: ' + title + '</p><p>Artist: ' + artist) // modal.find('.modal-body input').val(title) }) </script>`

Comment: `$(this) modal.find('.modal-title').text(` converted to `$(this) modal.find('.modal-title').html(`

Comment: @MohammadHamedani Please don't update your question in the comments. I have edited the question to include your update.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this answer, if it worked.